# GLThread throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

Im trying to set my initial game state in my GLSurefaceView.Renderer class, and create my Sprite Object in InitialGameState(Context) and calling it methods in render() but a exception get thrown in GLThread.

```
public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer 
{
    private Context m_context;
    private GameStateManager m_game;

    public MyRenderer(Context context) 
    {
        m_context = context;
        m_game = GameStateManager.getInstance();
        m_game.setGameState(new InGame(m_context));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
    {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        m_game.getCurrentState().render();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) 
    {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
    {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f);
        ShaderManager.getInstance().createDefaultShaders(m_context);


    }
}


public class InGame extends GameState
{
    private Sprite m_sprite;
    private boolean m_isInitialized = false;

    public InGame(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);

        m_sprite = new Sprite(m_context);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() 
    {
        if (!m_isInitialized)
        {

            m_sprite.create("clover.png");
            m_isInitialized = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_sprite.begin();
            m_sprite.draw();
            m_sprite.end();
        }   
    }
}
```

everything works fine when i call m_game.setGameState(new InGame(context)) in onSurfaceCreated(). can this be fixed?

```
Thread [<9> GLThread 10] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))   
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run() line: 1122
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the thrown exception

Comment: how do i get the trace for that exception in eclipse?

Comment: Ok, next step, the stack trace I saw briefly listed the exception as coming from `MyRenderer` line 26 - I didn't make a note of what method that was in, but it should point pretty clearly to your problem.

Comment: MyRenderer.<init>? is that suppose to be the constructor?

Comment: Yes, that's how Java refers to the constructor of a class (its `init`ialization)